# Juniper firewall - large pings for testing

Tags: firewall, ping, juniper

Is there an way to permit ping packets larger than 1472 through a Juniper SSG520M firewall?

"Ping of Death" and "Large Size ICMP Packet" protection has already been disabled under the 'Screening' options.

I need to be able to ping from the Trust side to the Untrust side (and perhaps vice versa) with packets larger than 1500 (i.e. ping 192.168.1.1 -l 4096) so I can force fragmentation.

Comment: Are you running JUNOS or ScreenOS on your SSG? I'd assume ScreenOS

Comment: Correct - ScreenOS v.6.2

Answer (score 1):

Note that linux ping by default these days seems to set the don't fragment bit. Check the man page for your implementation (as there are several depending on distribution *sigh*).

For the "iputils" version you want the "-M dont" option.

Comment: This was done from an XP machine.
The don't fragment bit, should cause the (in this case) firewall to reply back to my machine with a smaller MTU size so my machine can fragment the traffic.  This is either not happening or the firewall is simply blocking the traffic because it violates some security setting.

Comment: What about logging on the Juniper? All drops should be traceable.

Comment: One more thing to check. Is the Juniper configured to block ICMP responses? That would stop the error response.

Answer (score 1):

If you login to the cli, you should be able to see why the ping is being dropped with ffilter
Something along the lines of 
`set ffilter dst-ip <whatever> src-ip <whatever>`

Should tell you what rule is actually dropping the ping, so you can turn it off.